# I have got a report of crushes java.lang.RuntimeException:

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tested my app at many devices without any problems, but I received many crushes reports from users.
Can you friends explain where the problem is? Some of the devices such as Samsung A7 gives the same crush, and I have one and does not give me any problem in the testing the app.

Thank you

Here is a report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.os.AsyncTask$AsyncFutureTask.done (AsyncTask.java:429)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:383)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:252)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:271)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:292)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:929)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.util.Log.println_native (Native Method)
  at android.util.Log.e (Log.java:265)
  at com.waddan.quran.MediaP$Player1.doInBackground (MediaP.java:262)
  at com.waddan.quran.MediaP$Player1.doInBackground (MediaP.java:231)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call (AsyncTask.java:389)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
```

The activity that makes the problem is MediaP, and here is its code:

```
public class MediaP extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView imagePlayPause;
private TextView textCurrentTime, textTotalDuration, tvTest;
private SeekBar playerSeekbar;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
public String kare, pageNum;
private Button btn_goback;
private ImageView img_showPage;
///***********************************************************
private boolean playPause;
private android.media.MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private boolean initiaStage = true;
//************************************************************
private Integer[] images = {R.drawable.a604, R.drawable.a603, R.drawable.a602, R.drawable.a601, R.drawable.a600, R.drawable.a599, R.drawable.a598, R.drawable.a597, R.drawable.a596, R.drawable.a595, R.drawable.a594, R.drawable.a593, R.drawable.a592, R.drawable.a591, R.drawable.a590, R.drawable.a589, R.drawable.a588, R.drawable.a587, R.drawable.a586, R.drawable.a585, R.drawable.a584, R.drawable.a583, R.drawable.a582, R.drawable.a581, R.drawable.a580, R.drawable.a579, R.drawable.a578, R.drawable.a577, R.drawable.a576, R.drawable.a575, R.drawable.a574, R.drawable.a573, R.drawable.a572, R.drawable.a571, R.drawable.a570, R.drawable.a569, R.drawable.a568, R.drawable.a567, R.drawable.a566, R.drawable.a565, R.drawable.a564, R.drawable.a563, R.drawable.a562, R.drawable.a561, R.drawable.a560, R.drawable.a559, R.drawable.a558, R.drawable.a557, R.drawable.a556, R.drawable.a555, R.drawable.a554, R.drawable.a553, R.drawable.a552, R.drawable.a551, R.drawable.a550, R.drawable.a549, R.drawable.a548, R.drawable.a547, R.drawable.a546, R.drawable.a545, R.drawable.a544, R.drawable.a543, R.drawable.a542, R.drawable.a541, R.drawable.a540, R.drawable.a539, R.drawable.a538, R.drawable.a537, R.drawable.a536, R.drawable.a535, R.drawable.a534, R.drawable.a533, R.drawable.a532, R.drawable.a531, R.drawable.a530, R.drawable.a529, R.drawable.a528, R.drawable.a527, R.drawable.a526, R.drawable.a525, R.drawable.a524, R.drawable.a523, R.drawable.a522, R.drawable.a521, R.drawable.a520, R.drawable.a519, R.drawable.a518, R.drawable.a517, R.drawable.a516, R.drawable.a515, R.drawable.a514, R.drawable.a513, R.drawable.a512, R.drawable.a511, R.drawable.a510, R.drawable.a509, R.drawable.a508, R.drawable.a507, R.drawable.a506, R.drawable.a505, R.drawable.a504, R.drawable.a503, R.drawable.a502, R.drawable.a501, R.drawable.a500, R.drawable.a499, R.drawable.a498, R.drawable.a497, R.drawable.a496, R.drawable.a495, R.drawable.a494, R.drawable.a493, R.drawable.a492, R.drawable.a491, R.drawable.a490, R.drawable.a489, R.drawable.a488, R.drawable.a487, R.drawable.a486, R.drawable.a485, R.drawable.a484, R.drawable.a483, R.drawable.a482, R.drawable.a481, R.drawable.a480, R.drawable.a479, R.drawable.a478, R.drawable.a477, R.drawable.a476, R.drawable.a475, R.drawable.a474, R.drawable.a473, R.drawable.a472, R.drawable.a471, R.drawable.a470, R.drawable.a469, R.drawable.a468, R.drawable.a467, R.drawable.a466, R.drawable.a465, R.drawable.a464, R.drawable.a463, R.drawable.a462, R.drawable.a461, R.drawable.a460, R.drawable.a459, R.drawable.a458, R.drawable.a457, R.drawable.a456, R.drawable.a455, R.drawable.a454, R.drawable.a453, R.drawable.a452, R.drawable.a451, R.drawable.a450, R.drawable.a449, R.drawable.a448, R.drawable.a447, R.drawable.a446, R.drawable.a445, R.drawable.a444, R.drawable.a443, R.drawable.a442, R.drawable.a441, R.drawable.a440, R.drawable.a439, R.drawable.a438, R.drawable.a437, R.drawable.a436, R.drawable.a435, R.drawable.a434, R.drawable.a433, R.drawable.a432, R.drawable.a431, R.drawable.a430, R.drawable.a429, R.drawable.a428, R.drawable.a427, R.drawable.a426, R.drawable.a425, R.drawable.a424, R.drawable.a423, R.drawable.a422, R.drawable.a421, R.drawable.a420, R.drawable.a419, R.drawable.a418, R.drawable.a417, R.drawable.a416, R.drawable.a415, R.drawable.a414, R.drawable.a413, R.drawable.a412, R.drawable.a411, R.drawable.a410, R.drawable.a409, R.drawable.a408, R.drawable.a407, R.drawable.a406, R.drawable.a405, R.drawable.a404, R.drawable.a403, R.drawable.a402, R.drawable.a401, R.drawable.a400, R.drawable.a399, R.drawable.a398, R.drawable.a397, R.drawable.a396, R.drawable.a395, R.drawable.a394, R.drawable.a393, R.drawable.a392, R.drawable.a391, R.drawable.a390, R.drawable.a389, R.drawable.a388, R.drawable.a387, R.drawable.a386, R.drawable.a385, R.drawable.a384, R.drawable.a383, R.drawable.a382, R.drawable.a381, R.drawable.a380, R.drawable.a379, R.drawable.a378, R.drawable.a377, R.drawable.a376, R.drawable.a375, R.drawable.a374, R.drawable.a373, R.drawable.a372, R.drawable.a371, R.drawable.a370, R.drawable.a369, R.drawable.a368, R.drawable.a367, R.drawable.a366, R.drawable.a365, R.drawable.a364, R.drawable.a363, R.drawable.a362, R.drawable.a361, R.drawable.a360, R.drawable.a359, R.drawable.a358, R.drawable.a357, R.drawable.a356, R.drawable.a355, R.drawable.a354, R.drawable.a353, R.drawable.a352, R.drawable.a351, R.drawable.a350, R.drawable.a349, R.drawable.a348, R.drawable.a347, R.drawable.a346, R.drawable.a345, R.drawable.a344, R.drawable.a343, R.drawable.a342, R.drawable.a341, R.drawable.a340, R.drawable.a339, R.drawable.a338, R.drawable.a337, R.drawable.a336, R.drawable.a335, R.drawable.a334, R.drawable.a333, R.drawable.a332, R.drawable.a331, R.drawable.a330, R.drawable.a329, R.drawable.a328, R.drawable.a327, R.drawable.a326, R.drawable.a325, R.drawable.a324, R.drawable.a323, R.drawable.a322, R.drawable.a321, R.drawable.a320, R.drawable.a319, R.drawable.a318, R.drawable.a317, R.drawable.a316, R.drawable.a315, R.drawable.a314, R.drawable.a313, R.drawable.a312, R.drawable.a311, R.drawable.a310, R.drawable.a309, R.drawable.a308, R.drawable.a307, R.drawable.a306, R.drawable.a305, R.drawable.a304, R.drawable.a303, R.drawable.a302, R.drawable.a301, R.drawable.a300, R.drawable.a299, R.drawable.a298, R.drawable.a297, R.drawable.a296, R.drawable.a295, R.drawable.a294, R.drawable.a293, R.drawable.a292, R.drawable.a291, R.drawable.a290, R.drawable.a289, R.drawable.a288, R.drawable.a287, R.drawable.a286, R.drawable.a285, R.drawable.a284, R.drawable.a283, R.drawable.a282, R.drawable.a281, R.drawable.a280, R.drawable.a279, R.drawable.a278, R.drawable.a277, R.drawable.a276, R.drawable.a275, R.drawable.a274, R.drawable.a273, R.drawable.a272, R.drawable.a271, R.drawable.a270, R.drawable.a269, R.drawable.a268, R.drawable.a267, R.drawable.a266, R.drawable.a265, R.drawable.a264, R.drawable.a263, R.drawable.a262, R.drawable.a261, R.drawable.a260, R.drawable.a259, R.drawable.a258, R.drawable.a257, R.drawable.a256, R.drawable.a255, R.drawable.a254, R.drawable.a253, R.drawable.a252, R.drawable.a251, R.drawable.a250, R.drawable.a249, R.drawable.a248, R.drawable.a247, R.drawable.a246, R.drawable.a245, R.drawable.a244, R.drawable.a243, R.drawable.a242, R.drawable.a241, R.drawable.a240, R.drawable.a239, R.drawable.a238, R.drawable.a237, R.drawable.a236, R.drawable.a235, R.drawable.a234, R.drawable.a233, R.drawable.a232, R.drawable.a231, R.drawable.a230, R.drawable.a229, R.drawable.a228, R.drawable.a227, R.drawable.a226, R.drawable.a225, R.drawable.a224, R.drawable.a223, R.drawable.a222, R.drawable.a221, R.drawable.a220, R.drawable.a219, R.drawable.a218, R.drawable.a217, R.drawable.a216, R.drawable.a215, R.drawable.a214, R.drawable.a213, R.drawable.a212, R.drawable.a211, R.drawable.a210, R.drawable.a209, R.drawable.a208, R.drawable.a207, R.drawable.a206, R.drawable.a205, R.drawable.a204, R.drawable.a203, R.drawable.a202, R.drawable.a201, R.drawable.a200, R.drawable.a199, R.drawable.a198, R.drawable.a197, R.drawable.a196, R.drawable.a195, R.drawable.a194, R.drawable.a193, R.drawable.a192, R.drawable.a191, R.drawable.a190, R.drawable.a189, R.drawable.a188, R.drawable.a187, R.drawable.a186, R.drawable.a185, R.drawable.a184, R.drawable.a183, R.drawable.a182, R.drawable.a181, R.drawable.a180, R.drawable.a179, R.drawable.a178, R.drawable.a177, R.drawable.a176, R.drawable.a175, R.drawable.a174, R.drawable.a173, R.drawable.a172, R.drawable.a171, R.drawable.a170, R.drawable.a169, R.drawable.a168, R.drawable.a167, R.drawable.a166, R.drawable.a165, R.drawable.a164, R.drawable.a163, R.drawable.a162, R.drawable.a161, R.drawable.a160, R.drawable.a159, R.drawable.a158, R.drawable.a157, R.drawable.a156, R.drawable.a155, R.drawable.a154, R.drawable.a153, R.drawable.a152, R.drawable.a151, R.drawable.a150, R.drawable.a149, R.drawable.a148, R.drawable.a147, R.drawable.a146, R.drawable.a145, R.drawable.a144, R.drawable.a143, R.drawable.a142, R.drawable.a141, R.drawable.a140, R.drawable.a139, R.drawable.a138, R.drawable.a137, R.drawable.a136, R.drawable.a135, R.drawable.a134, R.drawable.a133, R.drawable.a132, R.drawable.a131, R.drawable.a130, R.drawable.a129, R.drawable.a128, R.drawable.a127, R.drawable.a126, R.drawable.a125, R.drawable.a124, R.drawable.a123, R.drawable.a122, R.drawable.a121, R.drawable.a120, R.drawable.a119, R.drawable.a118, R.drawable.a117, R.drawable.a116, R.drawable.a115, R.drawable.a114, R.drawable.a113, R.drawable.a112, R.drawable.a111, R.drawable.a110, R.drawable.a109, R.drawable.a108, R.drawable.a107, R.drawable.a106, R.drawable.a105, R.drawable.a104, R.drawable.a103, R.drawable.a102, R.drawable.a101, R.drawable.a100, R.drawable.a99, R.drawable.a98, R.drawable.a97, R.drawable.a96, R.drawable.a95, R.drawable.a94, R.drawable.a93, R.drawable.a92, R.drawable.a91, R.drawable.a90, R.drawable.a89, R.drawable.a88, R.drawable.a87, R.drawable.a86, R.drawable.a85, R.drawable.a84, R.drawable.a83, R.drawable.a82, R.drawable.a81, R.drawable.a80, R.drawable.a79, R.drawable.a78, R.drawable.a77, R.drawable.a76, R.drawable.a75, R.drawable.a74, R.drawable.a73, R.drawable.a72, R.drawable.a71, R.drawable.a70, R.drawable.a69, R.drawable.a68, R.drawable.a67, R.drawable.a66, R.drawable.a65, R.drawable.a64, R.drawable.a63, R.drawable.a62, R.drawable.a61, R.drawable.a60, R.drawable.a59, R.drawable.a58, R.drawable.a57, R.drawable.a56, R.drawable.a55, R.drawable.a54, R.drawable.a53, R.drawable.a52, R.drawable.a51, R.drawable.a50, R.drawable.a49, R.drawable.a48, R.drawable.a47, R.drawable.a46, R.drawable.a45, R.drawable.a44, R.drawable.a43, R.drawable.a42, R.drawable.a41, R.drawable.a40, R.drawable.a39, R.drawable.a38, R.drawable.a37, R.drawable.a36, R.drawable.a35, R.drawable.a34, R.drawable.a33, R.drawable.a32, R.drawable.a31, R.drawable.a30, R.drawable.a29, R.drawable.a28, R.drawable.a27, R.drawable.a26, R.drawable.a25, R.drawable.a24, R.drawable.a23, R.drawable.a22, R.drawable.a21, R.drawable.a20, R.drawable.a19, R.drawable.a18, R.drawable.a17, R.drawable.a16, R.drawable.a15, R.drawable.a14, R.drawable.a13, R.drawable.a12, R.drawable.a11, R.drawable.a10, R.drawable.a9, R.drawable.a8, R.drawable.a7, R.drawable.a6, R.drawable.a5, R.drawable.a4, R.drawable.a3, R.drawable.a2, R.drawable.a1

};


@SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "SourceLockedOrientationActivity"})
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_p);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //  this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);

    mediaPlayer = new android.media.MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    kare = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_KARE1");
    imagePlayPause = findViewById(R.id.image_playPause);
    textCurrentTime = findViewById(R.id.textCurrentTime);
    textTotalDuration = findViewById(R.id.textTotalDuration);
    img_showPage = findViewById(R.id.img_showPage);
    btn_goback = findViewById(R.id.btn_goack);
    tvTest = findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
    pageNum = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_PAGE");
    tvTest.setText("ص  "+pageNum);

    // et_go=findViewById(R.id.et_go);
    playerSeekbar = findViewById(R.id.playerSeekar);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    playerSeekbar.setMax(100);
    //////show page image in the image view
    String uri = "@drawable/a" + pageNum; //imname without extension

    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName()); //get image  resource

    Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource); // convert into drawble

    img_showPage.setImageDrawable(res); // set as image

    //////show page image in the image view end

    imagePlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String url = "";
            if (kare.equals("1")) {
                url = "https://ia802309.us.archive.org/32/items/mshary-al3afasy-by-qasr-almonfasel-604-page-quran-mp3-128kb_21/";
            } else if (kare.equals("2")) {
                url = "https://ia902609.us.archive.org/32/items/64kb--yaser--aldosry---quran--mp3---604--part---full/";
            } else if (kare.equals("3")) {
                url = "https://ia801306.us.archive.org/3/items/rabiea3568356835683568865/";
            }
            String tt = pageNum;// for testing
            int mm = Integer.parseInt(pageNum);
            if (mm < 10) {
                tt = "00" + pageNum;
            } else if (mm < 100 & mm > 10) {
                tt = "0" + pageNum;
            } else tt = pageNum;
            String yy = url + tt + ".mp3";
            if (!playPause) {
                updateSeekbar();

                if (initiaStage) {
                    new Player1().execute(yy);
                    imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);

                    updateSeekbar();
                } else {
                    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    updateSeekbar();
                }
                playPause = true;
                imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);

            } else {

                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(updater);//*********************
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                    updateSeekbar();

                }
                playPause = false;

            }
        }
    });

    playerSeekbar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view;
            int playPosition = (mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 100) * seekBar.getProgress();
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPosition);
            textCurrentTime.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
            return false;


        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int i) {
            playerSeekbar.setSecondaryProgress(i);
            ;
            updateSeekbar();


        }
    });

    btn_goback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
            finish();

        }
    });


}

//**********************
class Player1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
   // @SuppressLint("WrongThread")
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Boolean prepared = false;


        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(android.media.MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    playerSeekbar.setProgress(0);
                    imagePlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                    textCurrentTime.setText(R.string.zero);
                    textTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    initiaStage = true;
                    playPause = false;

                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();

                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            textTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));


            prepared = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyAudioStreaminApp", e.getMessage());
            prepared = false;

        }

        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.cancel();
            updateSeekbar();

        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
        initiaStage = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        String yo=pageNum;
        progressDialog.setMessage("جاري تحميل الصفحه     "+pageNum);
        progressDialog.show();

    }


}

private Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateSeekbar();

    }
};

private void updateSeekbar() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        handler.postDelayed(updater, 1000);
        playerSeekbar.setProgress((int) (((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mediaPlayer.getDuration()) * 100));

        textCurrentTime.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));

    }
}

private String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliSeconds) {
    String timerString = "";
    String secondsString;
    int hours = (int) (milliSeconds / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    int minutes = (int) (milliSeconds % (100 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
    int seconds = (int) ((milliSeconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);
    if (hours > 0) {
        timerString = hours + ":";

    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        secondsString = "0" + seconds;
    } else {
        secondsString = "" + seconds;
    }
    timerString = timerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;
    return timerString;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mediaPlayer.stop();


}
```

}

Comment: As your question there, `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:` . You need to trace where is the null come from

Comment: Error is when you are logging in the catch of try and catch, Make sure e.getMessage() is not null. Change **Log.e("MyAudioStreaminApp", e.getMessage());** to **Log.e("MyAudioStreaminApp", (e.getMessage() != null) ? e.getMessage() : "");**

Comment: Actually, a better fix would be `Log.e("MyAudioStreaminApp", "media player problem", e)`.  That will also give you the exception class name and the stacktrace for the original exception.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot tell you the ultimate cause of your problem because the information about the cause has been lost due to "bad logging".

What has happened is that your code has caught an exception here:

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyAudioStreaminApp", e.getMessage());
        prepared = false;
    }
```

For some reason the exception has a `null` message.  (We don't know why.  An exception is not *required* to have a non-null message.  At this stage we could only *guess* what the exception actually was, though it is probably specific to the media player implementation on certain devices.).

So, you are effectively calling:

```
  Log.e("MyAudioStreaminApp", null);
```

But the javadoc for the `Log.e` methods say explicitly that the message must be non-null.  So the above results in an NPE being thrown in the depths of the logging code.  (Instead of logging the problem you wanted to log, you get something unhelpful.)

---

The solution (to the NPEs) is to change the logger call to this:

```
 Log.e("MyAudioStreaminApp", "problem playing media", e);
```

Why:

1. So that you don't get tripped up by the edge case where the exception has a `null` message.
2. So that you do log the classname of the exception.
3. So that you do log the stacktrace embedded in the exception.  That will at least point you to where in your code the exception is triggered, and it may also give you further insights ... depending on what the actual media player does internally.

The next step will be to test the modified app on a Samsung A7, and see what is logged.

---

The suggestion in the comments to do this:

```
Log.e("MyAudioStreaminApp", (e.getMessage() != null) ? e.getMessage() : "");
```

is (IMO) wrong.  You won't get the NPE in the logging code, but you will be no clearer to figuring out what the root cause of the problems is.  (You will just get useless log entries with no information in them.)

---

The lesson from this is to use the `Log` method overloads with a `Throwable` argument when logging from an exception handler.  It is a good habit (IMO).

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen. you explained the cause of the problem very clearly. I appreciate your helpful suggestions.